# form_for instance variable wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

My form_for is not passing as a form.  I can usually troubleshoot through problems, but this one I cannot figure out why 2 arguments are being passed from `@image`.  Here is my code

**Error**

```
wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
```

**View**

```
<% form_for @image, :action => "edit" do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
    <%= f.submit "Update" %>
<% end %>
```

**Controller**

```
class Admin::ImagesController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :html, :json
    def index
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
        @images = Image.all
    end
    def new
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
        @image = @album.images.new(params[:image_id])
    end
    def create
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
        @image = @album.images.new(params[:image])
        if @image.save
            flash[:notice] = "Successfully added image!"
            redirect_to [:admin, @album, :images]
        else
            render :action => 'new'
        end
    end
    def show
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
        @image = @album.images(params[:id])
    end
    def edit
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
        @image = @album.images(params[:id])
    end
    def update
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
        @image = @album.images(params[:id])
        if @image.update_attributes(params[:image])
            flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated Image"
            redirect_to @image
        else
            render :action => "edit"
        end
    end
    def destroy
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
        @image = Image.find(params[:id])
        @image.destroy
        redirect_to admin_album_images_path(@album)
    end

end
```

**Routes**

```
Admin::Application.routes.draw do
  get "albums/index"

  get "dashboard/index"

  namespace :admin do
    root :to => "dashboard#index"
    resources :dashboard
    resources :albums do
      resources :images
     end
    get "admin/album"
    end
    get "logout" => "sessions#destroy", :as => "logout"
  get "login" => "sessions#new", :as => "login"
  get "signup" => "users#new", :as => "signup"
    # resources :users
  resources :basic
    root :to => "basic#index"
```

**Model**

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :title, :description, :image_name, :image_id, :album_id
    belongs_to :album
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :album
end
```

Comment: My only red flag would be this code `@image = @album.images(params[:id])` aren't you supposed to do `@image = @album.images.where(id: params[:id])`?

Comment: That's on your edit action that I'm assuming is being passed off to your form through the @image ivar.

Comment: It references the image correctly how it is... it just produces an arguments error when used in the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your form code to the following:

```
<%= form_for @image, :url => { :action => "edit" } do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
    <%= f.submit "Update" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @derek_duncan oops. There is a missing `=` in the first line. I've updated the code, try changing it again.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `find` keyword:

```
 def edit
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
        @image = @album.images.find(params[:id])
 end
```

The same thing goes with the `update` and `show` action in your controller.

With:

```
    @image = @album.images(params[:id])
```

your `@images` is going to contain all images from the album.

Comment: This works fine.  If I `debug @image`, it references the image correctly.  I just don't know why it has `wrong arguments error` when used in the edit.html.erb form

Comment: You probably have one image in that album? that's why it is KIND OF referencing it right, but actually it is going to return an array containing that one image, and it can perform that action on a array.

Comment: Yes I only have one image in that album for testing.  However, I am just trying to select the specific image being edited...

Comment: Did you try this solution?

Comment: How does your form get shown if you have: `<% form_for @image, :action => "edit" do |f| %>` instead of `<%=..` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for